# change the db when the time ran out

Tags: django

i'm writing a django app that features a timer like in a game.

lets say that the game is a basketball game and i have 4 quarters of 10 min.

i need that in the end of each of the 10 min the db will be changed.

to set a timer that will change the db won't work for me because the quarter

won't always be of 10 min, and it will be changed while the app is on

production, i.e  i save the quarter time in the db so i can change it whenever

i want.

i thought to use signals but i just could't find a way to make it work.

any help will be good

thx

Answer (score 1):

one way to think about it would be to say it doesn't matter what state the db is in when nobody is looking at it... in other words you don't have to update the db after exactly 10 minutes

instead: as each request comes in first check if you are past the limit of the timer, if so then update the db before continuing with the usual view code

Comment: that is actually a good idea.. but.. it won't be good for me. lets say i have 8 games and only one can be played at a time, when the first end i need to disable it, before another request will come

Comment: but what does it mean to 'disable' the game in between requests? as far as the server is concerned nothing is happening. you could easily have multiple concurrent games each with different length quarters using the above method